# How do I calculate the absolute min(m) and absolute Max(M) on an interval [a,b] using properties of integrals?

Tags: riemann-sum, riemann-integration, maxima-minima

If:

$$ m ≤ f(x) ≤ M \ for \ a ≤ x ≤ b $$

where m is the absolute minimum and M is the absolute maximum of f on the interval [a, b], then:

$$ m(b − a) ≤ \int f(x)dx \ a ≤ M(b − a).$$

Use this property to estimate the value of the integral.

$$ \int_\frac{π}{16}^\frac{π}{12} 7*tan (4x) dx $$

first things first, I know that f(x) is an increasing function from:

$$ \frac{π}{16} \ to \frac{π}{12} $$

Therefore: I should use the Comparison properties of the Integral to Solve this which states that:

If:

$$ m \le f(x) \le M \ for a \le x \le b,$$

then:

$$ m(b-a) \le \int_a^bf(x)dx \le M(b-a) $$

When graph this problem it looks like the graph is increasing and approach m = 7 and M = ~10

However, I just dont know how to calculate these Estimates.

I tried using that property to solve by using:

m = f(pi/16) = 7

and

M = f(pi/12) = 12.12436

but that was incorrect....

How do I start to solve this one?

Comment: But your function is $\tan(4x)$, so $m=\tan(4\cdot \frac{\pi}{16})$ and $M=\tan(4\cdot \frac{\pi}{12})$.

Comment: i thought that was implied when I wrote f(pi/12)....

Comment: do you know what I am doing wrong... even when I plug into ti-89 i get same results...

Comment: sorry, I oversaw that. But how do you know that your estimates are incorrect?

Comment: because the system tells me that the result is incorrect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you did the right thing, or at least intended to approach this correctly.

You are right that $\tan(4x)$ is increasing on $[\tfrac{\pi}{16},\tfrac{\pi}{12}]$ so:
$$\tan(4\tfrac{\pi}{16}) \le \tan(4x) \le \tan(4\tfrac{\pi}{12}) \quad \mbox{for} \quad x \in [\tfrac{\pi}{16},\tfrac{\pi}{12}]$$
which means that using your notation, you have for $f(x)=7\tan(4x)$:
$$m = 7\tan(4\tfrac{\pi}{16}) = 7\tan(\tfrac{\pi}{4}) = 7\quad \mbox{and} \quad M = 7\tan(4\tfrac{\pi}{12}) = 7\tan(\tfrac{\pi}{3}) = 7\sqrt{3}$$
From the theorem you mention, you then have with $b-a = \tfrac{\pi}{12}-\tfrac{\pi}{16}=\tfrac{\pi}{48}$:
$$m(b-a) \le \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,\mbox{d}x \le M(b-a) \to 7\frac{\pi}{48} \le \int_{\tfrac{\pi}{16}}^{\tfrac{\pi}{12}} 7\tan(4x) \,\mbox{d}x \le 7\sqrt{3}\frac{\pi}{48}$$

---

To have an idea, the values are approximately:

- $7\frac{\pi}{48} \approx 0.458 $
- $\int_{\tfrac{\pi}{16}}^{\tfrac{\pi}{12}} 7\tan(4x) \,\mbox{d}x = \tfrac{\ln 2}{8} \approx 0.606 $
- $7\sqrt{3}\frac{\pi}{48} \approx 0.794 $

Comment: thank you for that. basically i just needed to keep going with the property as specified.